# m2eclipse (in Mule Studio 1.3.0) is not creating a source folder for my additional resources directory

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, mule

I have added the following to my project's pom.xml:

```xml
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/app</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

I am running Mule Studio 1.3.0, which is based on Eclipse 3.6 (Helios).  I have added m2eclipse 1.1.0.20120530-0009 via the update site.

The problem is that the directory src/main/app is not appearing as a source folder, and therefore its contents are not on the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the **src/main/app** folder as a resource is not totally correct from a mule point of view.

In fact this will mess up with the generated [Mule application structure](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Application+Format) and the content fo the app folder will end up both in the root of the zip and in the classes folder.

Instead the **src/main/app** folder should be part of the test resources and you can do that by adding the following plugin to your maven build:

```xml
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.7</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>add-source</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <sources>
                <source>${basedir}/src/main/app/</source>
            </sources>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right.  Since I don't need compilation, I added a testResources configuration instead.  I think it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell m2e to update its configuration. Right-click on your project > Maven > Update project ...

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow on for future readers, here is what I have in my pom now that works:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>add-test-resource</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/app</directory>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```